# How to reinstall Windows 8 in a dual boot configuration with Windows 7?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

My computer is running slow and I think I have some malware on it (high unknown network activity in wireshark, jumping mouse cursor, sudden high CPU / fan usage...). I want to format my Windows 8 and reinstall it.

The problem is, I have a dual boot with Windows 7 (for some school project requiring SurfaceSDK). Are there special steps I need to take and is it even possible to keep this Windows 7? I'm especially worried about the boot manager...

I've been searching on Google (and here) but I can't find the same configuration as I have (Win8 and Win7).

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: A Win8 [reset](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) should help you easily accomplish what you want without any grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily edit your boot entries with a program such as [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It will handle Windows 8 and Windows 7. I've tried it. It works.

Even if you overwrite your boot settings when installing Windows 8, you can restore the dual boot screen with EasyBCD. (I am not aware of any [alternatives](http://www.google.com/search?q=Alternative%20to%20easybcd).)